# SQL Server 2017 and TLS - client requirements

Tags: sql-server-2017, tls-1.2

I am testing something around SSL\TLS and SQL Server 2017. I have enabled TLS on a test SQL Server instance by creating a self-signed cert and doing the required steps to add it to the Windows certificate store and then adding it to SQL Server in Configuration Manager. I have set also 'Force Encryption' to 'On', and restarted the service. So as far as I can ascertain that is enough to enable TLS on the SQL Server side.

For client applications on other computers connecting to the SQL Server instance I am confused as to what the connection string requirements are for connections using SqlClient. My understanding from reading up on it was that 'TrustServerCertificate=true' would have to be added to the connection string, but it seems possible to connect without that.

Is this because the certificate on the server is seen as being from a trusted authority?

Comment: What is the value for `encrypt_option` in `sys.dm_exec_connections`?

Comment: TRUE across the board

Comment: Are you sure it's self-signed, rather than signed by your in-house CA? Is the SQL Server machine also the CA machine?

Comment: @Charlieface I did it myself with PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no,

```
TrustServerCertificate=true
```

means more or less

*ignore certification source verification*

It's used in env like your when a self-signed certificate is used for encryption.
It's better to use the certificate produced by a **CA** and distributed by your **AD GPO**.
In that case you don't need to use 'TrustServerCertificate=true'; but be sure to use in the connection string the **FQDN** of the server that is inside the certificate.